# Do asp.net validators handle client-side validation?

Tags: asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I've gotten myself very confused I think.

I'm looking at an ASP.NET 2.0 web project which uses `CustomValidator`s and `RequiredFieldValidator`s extensively. Some pages seem to do their validation on the server-side, while some do it client-side. None of the validators I have found set the `ClientValidationFunction`; all the `CustomValidator`s set the `OnServerValidate` property.

Whenever I look online for ways to do client-side validation with these validators, they always mention the `ClientValidationFunction` property as the way to do it. But I know asp.net must handle the client-side validation automatically as well somehow - I have a page that does it, and ran the debugger waiting for the page to be invalidated, and it goes through WebResource.axd, which obviously is Microsoft code.

So the answer to this question must be yes but... just as a sanity check, do these validators handle client-side validation as well as server-side?

If so, is there somewhere where this is configured where I can begin to look if I'm having problems with this client-side validation?

Comment: You can use CustomValidator's ClientValidationFunction property to specify client side validation function.with other validators i don't think it is possible to do client side validation

Comment: Put some example of your code. There may be some other things in your tags of `.aspx` page.